# Emulating a join which uses a contains operator opposed to equals?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have found that the `join` operator [does not allow the use of `Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause) and thus [only performs equijoins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-custom-join-operations). However, I need to perform a "not equijoin".

I specifically need to write a query with the following setup. Given two types of objects `Class` and `Student`

```
public class Class
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public List<Guid> Students { get; set; } = new List<Guid>();
}

public class Student
{
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public int Grade { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

Where a `Class` references its `Student` by their `StudentId`. I would like to write a clause which finds all `Class` in which the average grade of all `Student` is above some value.

---

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create all of the students
        var class1Students = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student() {Grade = 70 },
            new Student() {Grade = 70 }
        };
        var class2Students = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student() {Grade = 80 },
            new Student() {Grade = 80 }
        };
        var class3Students = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student() {Grade = 90 },
            new Student() {Grade = 90 }
        };
        var allStudents = new List<Student>();
        allStudents.AddRange(class1Students);
        allStudents.AddRange(class2Students);
        allStudents.AddRange(class3Students);

        // Create all of the classes
        var class1 = new Class()
        {
            Name = "Class1",
            Students = class1Students.Select(s => s.StudentId).ToList()
        };
        var class2 = new Class()
        {
            Name = "Class2",
            Students = class2Students.Select(s => s.StudentId).ToList()
        };
        var class3 = new Class()
        {
            Name = "Class3",
            Students = class3Students.Select(s => s.StudentId).ToList()
        };
        var allClasses = new List<Class>() { class1, class2, class3  };

        // Get all classes where the average grade is above 70
        var query = from cls in allClasses
                    join std in allStudents on 


    }
}
```

---

I would like to write the query like so

```
var query = from cls in allClasses
    join std in allStudents on cls.Students.Contains(std.StudentId) into clsStds
    where clsStds.Select(aStd => aStd.Grade).Average() > 70
    select cls;
```

Though this is obviously invalid syntax. The [page linked above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-custom-join-operations) provides an example of a non-equijoin though I have tried to apply it here and can not seem to reproduce it correctly (and/or I have seriously confused myself).

**How can I emulate the type of `join` I describe above?**

Comment: So you want only students who have grade above 70 in all classes?

Comment: I want the reverse, I want all classes in which the average grade of its students is above 70.

Comment: You tagged the question `IQueryable` but you appear to be using LINQ to Objects; can you explain why the tag?  The solution I gave with the lookup presumes LINQ to Objects.

Comment: The `IQueryable` comes from the use of the `LinqExtension` in MongoDB. This question represents a simpler and analogous situation to a query I wish to build to a MongoDB I have (Thus the odd data model you mention in your answer).

Comment: Sorry, the `IMongoQueryable`, I just realized here the Mongo specific usage of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, your data model is wrong.  Students do not have a single grade. **They have a grade in a class, and your model does not account for that**.  You need a third table, with columns student, class and grade.  I strongly recommend that you fix that.

Solving the problem as stated is straightforward, but I don't like any of the solutions presented so far.  They're mostly reasonable but could be a lot more efficient and robust.

The fundamental problem that you have is: you don't have a fast and easy way to go from the student ID to the student object. **Solve that problem first**:

```
var idToStudent = allStudents.ToLookup(s => s.id);
```

Great. Now the solution is straightforward:

```
var query = 
  from cls in allClasses
  let grades = from id in cls.Students select idToStudent(id).Grade
  where grades.Any()
  where grades.Average() > 70
  select cls;
```

Note that we are testing whether there are `Any` grades because there could be a class with no students. `Average` will crash if asked to take an average of zero items, so it is wise to check.

When you fix your data model so that you are relating students, classes and grades correctly, it will be:

```
var query = 
  from cls in allClasses
  let grades = 
    from grade in allGrades 
    where grade.Class == cls 
    select grade.grade
  where grades.Any()
  where grades.Average() > 70
  select cls;
```

In a properly designed set of tables, student ids don't come into it when computing an average; you relate the grades and the classes directly.

Now, you started this question by noting that you need a kind of join that C# doesn't support.  No, **you need to fix your data relationships** and then C# supports the kind of join you need! The above can be written more efficiently as

```
var query = 
  from cls in allClasses
  join g in allGrades on cls equals g.Class into grades
  where grades.Average() > 70
  select cls;
```

The need to check for Any disappears since C# will not produce an empty group.

That's the join you need; design your tables correctly and then use it!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Entity Framework or similar? Do you have navigation properties between the entities? If so, perhaps you can `GroupBy` on the students, and then navigate to the parent object. Something like:

```
    var query = allStudents
        .GroupBy(i=>i.Class)
        .Select(i=>new{
            Class = i,
            Average = i.Average(j=>j.Grade)
        })
        .Where(i=>i.Average > 70)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the Entity Framework, I have seen it many places before but I am not sure what it is or used for. The question is arising from trying to query a MongoDB in the manner specified in the question.

Comment: Ah, I see. Entity Framework is an ORM for data layers, and (among other things) generates classes for the objects in your data store. It's convenient because it allows you to work with your data layer in an object-oriented way, without a lot of effort.

Comment: Do you have any way to get from student to class in your model?

Comment: There is no way to go from `Student` to `Class`. Only `Class` references `Student` (through the `Guid` id), `Student` has "no idea" its even in a class.

Answer (score 0):

I found a sort of naive solution to the problem. First we "resolve" the `Guid` references in student to actual `Student` objects

```
var clsStd = 
    from cls in allClasses
    select new
    {
        cls,
        stdObjs = allStudents.Where(aStd => cls.Students.Contains(aStd.StudentId))
    };
```

Then we can query this collection of anonymous objects

```
var classes = 
   from clsStdObj in clsStd
   where clsStdObj.stdObjs.Select(stdObj => stdObj.Grade).Average() > 70
   select clsStdObj.cls;
```

This then resolves to the "set of all classes in which the average student grade is above 70".

But I am still open to less naive solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution (Thanks to @EricLippert for the advice on using `Any()` to avoid possible crash when `classGrades` is empty):

```
var query = from _class in allClasses
            let classGrades = from std in allStudents
                           where _class.Students.Contains(std.StudentId)
                           select std.Grade
            where classGrades.Any()
            where classGrades.Average() > 70
            select _class;
```

Essentially, for each `Class` I create a new sub-query where I select all `Student`s that are in that `Class`, and I project only the `Grade`, so the result is an `IEnumerable<string>`. Next part is easy: `Average()` on the grades.

Just out of curiosity, I have used a `Stopwatch` to compare your solution to mine and even if it is purely indicative, the ratio between delay times (mine / yours) is about 0.02 .

Comment: This is a reasonable attempt at a solution but there are a couple of problems. If there is a class with no students then `Average` crashes; you might add `where classGrades.Any`. Second, it is a little strange to iterate over all the students and pull out the ones in the class when the class already has a list of member students!

Comment: @EricLippert thank you for remind me of the `Average` crash, I did not think about it. However about the second point, I know it is strange but I chose to provide him a solution given his model and constraints. I read your answer and you are absolutely right, because you underlined the problem behind this.